# liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Syntax error in SQL statement " CREATE EXTENSION[*] UUID-OSSP;

Tags: spring-boot, h2, liquibase

Im using postgres with liquibase on cloud and h2db on my local machine. When i write sql queries for generating uuid, i get the error during build:

```
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Syntax error in SQL statement " CREATE EXTENSION[*] UUID-OSSP;
```

So i removed ossp extension and used gen_random_uuid() instead. And i get the below eror:

```
Caused by: liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: 
liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set db/scripts/123_Somescripts.sql::raw::includeAll:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Syntax error in SQL statement "
```

I start getting this error during build when i include H2 DB dependency. Otherwise the build works fine.

BUT, even if build works fine, i get the error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).


Process finished with exit code 0
```

I configured postgres db in appication-local.yml, and activated local profile but build still fails.

Comment: Well, obviously `create extension` is not valid for H2